# gcc compiler is not allocating memory contigously

Tags: c, memory, gcc, memory-management

I writing a simple program, after declaring a variables I am checking the addresses of variables  but memory is not allocated contiguously there are gaps in between.
here is my program. why is leaving gaps i am not understanding

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdint.h >

int main()
{

        char char_one,char_two;
        int a = 5,b = 7,*ptr,*ptr_one;
        static  int *sum_ptr;
        printf("address   of   a             %u\n",&a);
        printf("address  of variable b       %u\n",&b);
        printf("address  of ptr variable     %u\n",&ptr);
        printf("address  of ptr_one variable %u\n",&ptr_one);
        printf("address of char_one var      %u\n",&char_one);
        printf("address of char_two var      %u\n",&char_two);
        return 0;
}
```

output:
address   of   a             2636128020

address  of variable b       2636128024

address  of ptr variable     2636128000

address  of ptr_one variable 2636128008

address of char_one var      2636128030

address of char_two var      2636128031

Comment: And so what? GCC can do whatever he "wants"

Comment: Why do you care?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?  If you really want to have them in a specific order, put them in a struct--then they will be kept in order.

Comment: Why do you believe that it should in this case?

Comment: most of the cases I observed contiguous allocations that's why I thought it will allocate memory in contiguous locations. Thanks for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: After allocating memory randomly, The memory left in between is it usable or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard does not require memory for variables to be allocated contiguously.  In fact, memory might not even be allocated at all if the compiler decides it can optimize by keeping a value in a register instead.

If you declare a struct, the contents of the struct will be ordered the way you declare them, but you still might need to consider how the data is aligned within the struct - for example, ints are aligned on 4-byte boundaries in many architectures.  So if you have:

```
struct foo
{
    char a;
    int b;
}
```

a is guaranteed to come before b in memory, but they will still be padded with extra bytes between them to keep the correct alignment (so it takes 8 bytes to store your struct, even though it only "really" needs 5).

Here's a good resource for how structure alignment works:

[The lost art of C structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing)

Comment: The contents of the struct are not necessarily contiguous. E.G. `struct bar { char a; float b;}` will have padding between a and b.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin: If there are gaps, they aren't contiguous. The standard does guarantee that they're allocated in declared the order.

Comment: I see the source of the misunderstanding, and have edited my answer accordingly - my usage of "contiguous" was correct only for certain definitions of "contiguous".

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary that compiler will allocate memory contiguously (excluding array, In case of structures may be padding there). It is free to allocate memory from where it finds a free location.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design and on purpose, even on a freshly booted machine you won't get contiguous malloc()s.
Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Upon request: address space layout randomization is a techique to make sure memory is allocated in a more or less unpredictable way to ensure attacks relying on a fixed address layout won't succeed. This makes it (more) difficult for an attacker to exploit known deficiencies (or even detect them first).

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because they lose their value when the link breaks. Please add more information to your answer.

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't really expect that applies to wikipedia links. I'll fix that.